# Sending and receiving a stream

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, stream, mp3

I would like to feed a binary stream of an mp3 from my Mac app and then receive it with another app. I've done some research but am still stuck. Since the source would be from a mp3 would I use NSInputStream? How would I be able to host this so I can go onto a different computer, open up the app, and receive the stream? Any guidance or code you find would be great!

Comment: NSOutputStream and NSInputStream don't care what kind of data you're sending across them. They're just I/O streams; nothing fancier than that. You can't hook up one to the other, though, as they can only go to/from memory or a file. There are better ways to do this, but I'll leave it to someone who has done it to recommend one.

Comment: @PeterHosey If you can, (It seems no one else is commenting), could you list these methods.